# supportedInterfaceOrientations not called in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController subclass and it has the below code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

// MARK: Methods

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    print(self.selectedIndex)
    if self.selectedIndex == 1 {
        return .Portrait
    }

    return .All


   }

}
```

The function `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is only called when I execute the app from an iphone. If I execute the app from my iPad mini it is not called. Any idea of the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is very strange, but if I deselect `Upside Down` from the device orientation for iPads `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If 'Requires full screen' setting from 'General' is enable, will allow the orientation delegate methods `shouldAutorotate`, `preferredInterfaceOrientation`, and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to fire.

Comment: Setting UIRequiresFullScreen to YES means that the app does not support multitasking anymore. This might be not a good idea depending on you use case. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1

Comment: It's a brutal solution, but this is the only working solution I found. Thank you!

Comment: I had to deselect "Supports multiple windows" to make it work.

Comment: This solution can lead to bugs like your splash screen loading upside down.